# Make custom user_meta as permalink for post

Tags: custom-field, wp-admin, permalinks

For an existing custom_user_meta="user_name" how can i create a permalink for post submitted by that user in the URL.

e.g. - for user_name="**srk489**" i want the permalink of the post "***post1***" posted by that user to be "http://localhost/**srk489**/***post1***".

To get the user meta i got the following function

```
get_user_meta($user_id, $key, $single);
```

When i searched i got the following code for adding custom post field in permalink

```
function custom_post_title($title) {
    global $post;
    $type = get_post_type($post->ID);
    if ($type== 'post') {
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $custom_field_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_post_title', true);
    if(isset($custom_field_title))
      return $title.'-'.$custom_field_title;
    else
      return $title;

    }
   return $title;
}
add_filter ('title_save_pre','custom_post_title');
```

How do i relate the user meta and post permalink with each other so that i can get user_meta as permalink?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. Wouldn't the username already be the "author"  Why can't you just use %author%/%postname% as your permalink structure?

Comment: yes that is what i want ....but i case of username....i want a custom_user_meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot i finally came up with this solution.

My custom post type is "**facility**" and the custom_user_meta="**organization_name**".

First go to `http://localhost/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` and choose custom structure - in the text box put `/%organization_name%/%postname%/`

After that put the below given code in `functions.php`

```
add_action('init', 'tdd_add_rewrite_rules2');
function tdd_add_rewrite_rules2(){
// Register custom rewrite rules
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%facility%', '([^/]+)', 'facility=');
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%organization_name%', '([^/]+)', '');
$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('facility', '/%organization_name%/facility/%facility%', false);
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'tdd_permalinks2', 10, 3); 
function tdd_permalinks2($permalink, $post, $leavename){ 
$no_data = get_the_author_meta('ID');;
$post_id = $post->ID;
if($post->post_type != 'facility' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')))  return $permalink;
// $var1 = get_post_meta($post_id, 'posts_solicitorspeciality', true);
$var1 = get_the_author_meta('organization_name');

$var1 = sanitize_title($var1);
if(!$var1) { $var1 = $no_data; }
$permalink = str_replace('%organization_name%', $var1, $permalink); 
return $permalink; 
}
```